# Run method is blocked on creating a new thread in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to create a new thread inside a run method of currently running thread. But new thread is not getting started and it is blocking the execution of currently running thread.

Run method of currently running thread.

```
public void run() {
        while(true){
            try{
                Message message = (Message)objIn.readObject();
                System.out.println("Received msg:"+message);
                if(message.type.equals("connection")){
                    if(message.content.equals("true")){
                        System.out.println("connection successful");
                        InetAddress senderIp = message.senderIp;
                        InetAddress receiverIp = message.receiverIp;
                        System.err.println(senderIp+"------"+receiverIp);
                        if(senderIp.getHostAddress().equals(receiverIp.getHostAddress())){
                            //first member of ring topology
                            System.err.println("first member");
                        }else{
                            System.err.println("not the first member");
                            ClientSideTempClient clientTemp = new ClientSideTempClient(receiverIp);
                            Thread obj1 = new Thread(clientTemp);
                            obj1.start();
                            System.out.println("after starting local client tread...");
                        }
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("something went wrong");
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
            }
       }
}
```

Class for new thread:
**ClientSideTempClient.java**

```
public class ClientSideTempClient implements Runnable{
    public Socket socket;
    public ObjectInputStream objIn;
    public ObjectOutputStream objOut;
    public ClientSideTempClient(InetAddress serverIp){
        try{
            System.err.println("trying to connect"+serverIp.getHostAddress());
            String ipAddress = serverIp.getHostAddress();
            socket = new Socket(ipAddress, 9010);
            objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            objOut.flush();
            objIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Exception in ClientSideTempClient"+e);
        }

    }
    public void sendMessageToLocalServer(Message msg){
        try {
            objOut.writeObject(msg);
            objOut.flush();
            System.out.println("Outgoing : "+msg.toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception in chatroom_client:"+e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        While(true){
            System.out.println("Execution started here");
        }
    }
}
```

I searched number of related answers for this on google, but i am not getting solution of it. Can anyone guide me to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this compile: `While(true){`? Does this every print: `System.out.println("Execution started here");`?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the constructor that's blocking?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : it's not printing anything.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : yes.... Something is not working properly in constructor...!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: execution stops at objIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

Comment: Yup, see the javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream-java.io.InputStream-).

Comment: Try sending some content from your client. That constructor blocks in order to read some header bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ClientSideTempClient` class creates and connects the `Socket` in its constructor, which is delaying your loop. The `Socket` and the object streams should be created in its own `run()` method, i.e. on its own thread.

NB You must catch `EOFException` and break out of that loop if you get it. Most other `IOExceptions` are fatal too, except `SocketTimeoutException.`